# Bad math environment delimiter: ntheorem with thmmarks, Display math and split

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, ntheorem

Using a combination of `\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}`, display math enclosed in `\[ \]` and a `\begin{split}` environment inside it, `pdflatex` freaks out completely:

`! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.`

This is the minimum (non)working example (obviously without theorem definitions, nor with the need to have a `split` environment there; those are not of the essence in showing the error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
    a = b
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

Also, a workaround is to use `\begin{equation*}` instead.

**EDIT:** I guess a question was missing: any ideas what the problem is up there?

Comment: Page 25 of `ntheorem`'s documentation says: "Naturally, `ntheorem.sty` will not work correctly in combination with other styles which change the handling of
1. theorem-like environments, or
2. environments concerned with the handling of endmarks, e.g. `\[...\]`,
`eqnarray`, etc."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `thmmarks` option (if you delete it from your code, the error vanishes); this problem is documented in page 25 of the `ntheorem` documentation:

> Naturally, `ntheorem.sty` will not work correctly in combination with
>   other styles which change the handling of
>
> 1. theorem-like environments, or
> 2. environments concerned with the handling of endmarks, e.g. `\[...\]`, `eqnarray`, etc."

As you have mentioned, the solution is to use `equation*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    a = b
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

One might wonder why `equation*` works whilst `\[...\]` doesn't if both are equivalent as far as `amsmath` is concerned; the reason is that `ntheorem` redefines `\[` and `\]` when the `thmmarks` option is activated and this definition is not compatible with the meaning expected by `amsmath`'s environments.